# What's different between AccessorMethodName and Style/AccessorMethodName

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I've been searching a while and still don't know what's different between these `AccessorMethodName` and in `.rubocop.yml` configuration file?

Since I saw my coworker change `Style/AccessorMethodName` to `AccessorMethodName`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rubocop has (unbelievably) still not released `v1.0` of the library. The developers still often make "breaking" changes by moving things around and altering behaviour.

The `AccessorMethodName` cop was [added](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#new-features-39) to `rubocop` in `v0.16`. ([Commit](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/commit/1ac25b882b53e97601f10d1bf7ed4c450043e18a#diff-4d9059990c47aef226fbaabe9607dbaf)).

In `v0.50`, it was [renamed](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/commit/d825a020510091b70a04f3db21fc4295f0cae186#diff-ffe3f42d3bcd3318d6fc6c834e3c31fa) from `Style/AccessorMethodName` to `Naming/AccessorMethodName`.

The exact behaviour of this cop, and the "correct name" for it, depends on your `rubocop` version. But essentially, it's the same thing.

Comment: Thank you!
I checked my version is `0.52.1` .
So I probably name it `Naming/AccessorMethodName` instead of  `Style/AccessorMethodName` and `AccessorMethodName `

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/aecd5eadfdcb57be213729d2e98fba7a3c02de6c/lib/rubocop/config.rb#L71

Check that line out. Looks like it was moved from Style to 'Naming'. Not sure if it should work without 'Naming/', but it might.

Can also see it here
http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rubocop/RuboCop/Config